# Изменяемый размер текста

Tags: android, android-textview

Появилась такая проблема, у меня есть `TextView` в котором текст имеет размер 24sp, на моём основном телефоне всё отлично помещается, а на втором телефоне из-за маленького экрана надпись не влезает. Так вот, можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы если надпись не влезала в бокс то автоматически менял размер текста с 24sp на 20sp.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 4):

Для таких целей можно использовать адаптивный размер текста в виджете. В xml добавляете такие поля:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

устанавливаете максимальный и минимальный размер, а так же шаг (`autoSizeStepGranularity`) и текст будет подстраиваться под размер виджета и экрана соответственно. Вот [документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать **dimens**, для этого даже есть готовые библиотеки: https://github.com/intuit/ssp. В проекте, все **sp** заменяются на кастомный тег, например, **ssp**. Приложение будет использовать подходящий размер из готовых dimen файлов, и в зависимости от расширения экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы думаете, что текст размером 24sp на вашем основном телефоне "хорошо помещается", то скорее всего вы ошибаетесь. Просто зайдите в глобальные настройки и увеличьте масштаб текста на максимально большой, с большой долей вероятности весь макет превратится в "нечто".
На англоязычном форуме уже давно обсуждается вопрос игнорировать или нет глобальную настройку пользователя по масштабу текста: окончательного ответа нет - это ваш выбор.

В SDK 26 появилась опция подстройки размера текста, но она бесполезна если пользователь хочет видеть на своем экране КРУПНЫЙ ТЕКСТ для удобства чтения.

В своих проектах, чтобы поддержать глобальную опцию масштабирования текста, я помещал `TextView` в `ScrollView` по месту как горизонтальную так и вертикальную.